# validation and duplicate update() in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

In my form `Voiture`, I want to do a validation system for the fields `immatriculation` and `num_vehicule`

Here i an overview:

[image]

If I edit the first recording ie the value of the field num_vehicule `000001`  per `0000032`and that I validate, I have an error message because the value of the field immatriculation already exists.

[image]

I don't understand the problem... Do you have an idea please?

```
'immatriculation' => 'required|string|max:15|min:6|unique:voitures,immatriculation',
'num_vehicule' => 'required|string|max:6|min:6|unique:voitures,num_vehicule',
'fk_modele' => 'required'
```

Thank you

Comment: Post your controller's update function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
'immatriculation' => 'string|max:255|unique:voitures,immatriculation,' . $this->voitures->id,
```

The syntax is

```
 'input_field' => 'unique:<table name>,<column name for this input field>, <unique id>, <unique id column in table>';
```

Comment: @user11124425 I have used Id as example, you need to use your unique key value, that you can access, may be primary key value, editing my answer to add a better syntax rule, so that it will be more clear to you.

Comment: @ Prafulla Kumar Sahu: For me, it's the variable `id` , it's my primary key  but it doesn't work ??

Comment: @user11124425 you need to use the value of that column, example if you are updating record having id 5, then you need to use 5 here and not `id`, if you want to mention column name, that will be the last parameter after the value.